# Bokeh Hover Tool: new callback source.data does not match the info i get

Tags: python, user-interface, bokeh

I'm new with bokeh and I'm trying to use the information that I get from clicking in a plot to do some math.
For this I'm using the hover tool but the info I get is not the same that the tool displays.
I wanted to know if there is someone who knows why this happens and how can i fix this.

Here is the code and a link to a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQhhi.png) of the issue (in the yellow box is the data from the hover tool and in the red box i the data that comes in the callback, you can see there are not the exact same values, and I need them to be the same)

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource


from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show #para generar la ventana con el gráfico

from bokeh.layouts import layout, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, Div
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, Select, TextInput
from bokeh.io import curdoc

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import sys

from numpy import std
from numpy import loadtxt
from math import factorial

data=loadtxt('sn1996cb-19961217.dat')
x0=data[:,0] 
x1=np.array(x0).tolist()
y0=data[:,1]
escala=10**(-int(math.log(abs(y0[0]),10)))
y1=np.array(y0*escala).tolist()


#g create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p = figure(title="simple spec example", x_axis_label='x1', y_axis_label='y1',tools="pan,box_zoom,tap,crosshair,hover,undo,reset,save")

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=x1, y=y1))

# add a line renderer with legend and line thickness
pglyph=p.line('x', 'y', source=source, legend="Temp.", line_width=2)


def callback(attr, old, new):
    # The index of the selected glyph is : new['1d']['indices'][0]
    print old
    print new
    print source.data['x'][new['0d']['indices'][0]]
    print source.data['y'][new['0d']['indices'][0]]

pglyph.data_source.on_change('selected',callback)

curdoc().add_root(column(p)
```

Thanks in advance
Here is some of the data I used:

```
   X              Y
   6225.4600      0.42105132
   6226.9300      0.40851378
   6228.4000      0.41226137
   6229.8700      0.47898918
   6231.3400      0.51904130
   6232.8100      0.49808285
   6234.2800      0.45037213
   6235.7500      0.46673489
   6237.2200      0.51155555
   6238.6900      0.49420002
   6240.1600      0.48368737
   6241.6300      0.52214003
   6243.1000      0.51462704
   6244.5700      0.46338871
   6246.0400      0.47318232
   6247.5100      0.51138723
   6248.9800      0.53088999
   6250.4500      0.51826417
   6251.9200      0.49449995
   6253.3900      0.51309162
   6254.8600      0.56977183
   6256.3300      0.57982910
   6257.8000      0.54101282
   6259.2700      0.56600857
   6260.7400      0.58002889
   6262.2100      0.51426512
   6263.6800      0.55789798
   6265.1500      0.62440109
   6266.6200      0.58302051
   6268.0900      0.57691693
   6269.5600      0.57917851
   6271.0300      0.56606054
   6272.5000      0.60100335
   6273.9700      0.60407531
   6275.4400      0.58860093
   6276.9100      0.58404815
   6278.3800      0.62732899
   6279.8500      0.65989542
   6281.3200      0.62683642
   6282.7900      0.62852168
   6284.2600      0.66012704
   6285.7300      0.72063363
   6287.2000      0.75088245
   6288.6700      0.76107347
   6290.1400      0.75134450
   6291.6100      0.68774039
   6293.0800      0.69790459
   6294.5500      0.72648430
   6296.0200      0.70348245
   6297.4900      0.72302675
   6298.9600      0.74398172
   6300.4300      0.82931107
   6301.9000      0.92150021
   6303.3700      0.90641701
   6304.8400      0.85761434
   6306.3100      0.83027059
   6307.7800      0.76714623
   6309.2500      0.76923496
   6310.7200      0.82726943
   6312.1900      0.81078577
   6313.6600      0.83812791
   6315.1300      0.86778289
   6316.6000      0.81616235
   6318.0700      0.83251935
   6319.5400      0.87024456
   6321.0100      0.86657965
   6322.4800      0.88162446
   6323.9500      0.91759354
   6325.4200      0.88207662
   6326.8900      0.89954311
   6328.3600      0.96470612
   6329.8300      0.98872250
```

Comment: Can you post a complete example? Either by linking to a data file, or updating the example to generate synthetic data? Without being able to run to investigate, the only thing that comes to mind is possibly that the old default policy was to always use the previous point on a segment. It was recently changed in `0.12.5` to be "nearest" which should be a better default http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/releases/0.12.5.html#default-tooltip-position-for-lines-changed-to-nearest-point

Comment: I have uploaded some of the data I used

Answer (score 0):

The default tooltip is configured to display the `x` and `y` positions of the ***cursor***. If you want exact values from your data column you need to tell it that explicitly using the `@colname` syntax in the tooltip format. (Bokeh has no way to know in general what might have named your data source columns)

```
# remove default 'hover' from tools list
p = figure(title="simple spec example", x_axis_label='x1', y_axis_label='y1',
           tools="pan,box_zoom,tap,crosshair,undo,reset,save")

# add a custom hover that actually prints from columns by specifying @x and @y
hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips=[ ("(x,y)", "(@x, @y)"), ]
)
p.add_tools(hover)
```

With this change:

[image]

Comment: bigreddot Thank you very much.